# can't place edittext correctly on emulator

Tags: android

I have a custom listview and want to put edittext inside it, I put it on the right but when I run, it went to left, like this:

on my graphical layout:
[image]

on my emulator:
[image]

it suppose to be on the right, this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterRuper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterKelas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterRuang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterNama"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="370dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="660dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterVST"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="750dp"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cekListVDokterVst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edtListVDokterType"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cekListVDokterVst"
       android:ems="10" >
       <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried clean it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the `CheckBox` which aligns to parent's right. Then with its id, make your `EditText` to its left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cekListVDokterVst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/edtListVDokterType"
       android:layout_width="50dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cekListVDokterVst"
       android:ems="10" >
       <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In a `RelativeLayout`, when you play with ids, you must declare firstly the views and its ids and then according to it, declare the attributes like *toLeftOf*, *above*, *below*, etc, on other views.

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- set the checkbox and your edittext to the first position -->
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cekListVDokterVst"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/cekListVDokterVst"
        android:ems="10" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <!-- set the other views according to the first ids above -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterRegister"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <!-- as I can see on your layout, you create the other views with 
         margin attributes, maybe you should create with toRightOf attribute.
         >>> instead of margin=100dp/190dp... >>> use the following -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterRuper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtListVDokterRegister"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterKelas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtListVDokterRuper"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtListVDokterRuang"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/edtListVDokterType"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtListVDokterKelas"
        android:text="@string/emptyString"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <!-- ... -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Last note: when you set a new id, you do `@+id/...` but when you need to use an id, do `@id/...` (without the `+`). You don't need to "recreate" an id.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't work, see my whole xml (edit). I also tried to edit `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/edtListVDokterType"` and change it to `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` but it my app crash